# Finding the min and max length of movies in sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite

I need to find the min and max length out of several hundred movies in a sqlite table. I've never done this before.

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE length = ?
```

The columns include `id`, `name`, `length`, `director`. `Length` is shown as `1:45:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming LENGTH is stored as a numeric type, generally you would do this for all numerics:

```
select min(length), max(length) from movies
```